# AngularJS click on ion-tab icon not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am having difficulties with a ion-tab icon on AngularJS. I am trying to implement a click action with the below code but nothing is showing up.

HTML

```
<ion-tab title="Share" icon="icon ion-android-share-alt" ui-sref="tabs.sharethis"> <ion-nav-view name="share-tab"></ion-nav-view></ion-tab>
```

JS

```
.state('tabs.sharethis', {
    url:'/sharethis',
    views:{
      'share-tab':{
        templateUrl:'templates/playlist.html'
      }
    }
  });
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, your code seems correct, can you put in a jsfiddle? That I can check it out.

Comment: where ng-click in your html tag ?
-- you should add this ng-click="actionName()"

Comment: `ng-click` is not needed if you are using `ui-sref`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/lordlabakdas/fhagqzb8/

Answer (score 0):

I put you code in this codepen, and it is working: https://codepen.io/mfnunes/pen/vgwKmg
 As you can see the is the equal yours:

Js:

```
.state('tabs.sharethis', {
    url:'/sharethis',
    views:{
      'share-tab':{
        templateUrl:'templates/playlist.html'
      }
    }
  })
```

Html:

```
<ion-tab title="Share" icon="icon ion-android-share-alt" ui-sref="tabs.sharethis"> 
            <ion-nav-view name="share-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>
```

Comment: Still not working @Marcos. Not sure why though. Have included my entire code as part of JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/lordlabakdas/fhagqzb8/